# Is there a through model in foreignkey in foreignkey like in manytomanyfield?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I'm starting a web-like esports. I have a class called the game and Tournament.
Tournament has a foreignkey with game. Game has objects pubg and clashroyale. When Tournament is created with game pubg it has to have a attribute called "prize_per_kill". but not with other games. It has to be unique to that Tournament when created with that game. How can i do this?

I thought about using manytomanyfield but a single Tournament has only one Game. so it must be foreignkey.
I expect special attributes to that tournament that i can iterate through in detail page.

'''

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User,through="Subscription")
    max_players = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    tourney_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    tourney_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tourney_pass = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    first_prize = models.IntegerField()
    second_prize = models.IntegerField()
    third_prize = models.IntegerField()
```

'''

'''

```
class Game(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Membership")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    desc = models.TextField()
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an abstract `Game` model, `PubgGame` and `ClashRoyaleGame` models that inherit from your abstract model. That will give you two main flexibilities:

1. As `Game` will be an abstract model, no table will be created for it. You'll only have tables for `PubgGame` etc. game models.
2. You can add specific fields for each game such as `prize_per_kill`.

But using this solutions will arise a problem; you abstract models can't be used as ForeignKey in other models. So you need to find a way to represent your `PubgGame` and `ClashRoyaleGame` models in one ForeignKey field. Django has a special field for that: [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations). You need to point to a CoontentType and an PositiveIntegerField to your GenericForeignKey to be able store primary key id's of your game models.

```py
# models.py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class Game(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Membership")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    desc = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PubgGame(Game):
    prize_per_kill = models.TextField() # I dont know what prize_per_kill means :)

class ClashRoyaleGame(Game):
    some_other_field = models.TextField()

class Tournament(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User,through="Subscription")
    max_players = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    tourney_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    tourney_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tourney_pass = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    first_prize = models.IntegerField()
    second_prize = models.IntegerField()
    third_prize = models.IntegerField()

    # GenericForeignKey related fields
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    game = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Then you can use these fields like:

```py
>>> from your_ap.models import Tournament, PubgGame
>>> pubg_game = PubgGame.objects.create(prize_per_kill="some value")
>>> tournament = Tournament.objects.create(game=pubg_game) # I'm not setting other fields for simplicity.
>>> tournament.save()
>>> tournament.game_object # This will give you a PubgGame model object
```